# confluence latex plugin - Unable to find DVI conversion log file

Tags: confluence

I have done my google searches but have not found an answer for my situation: confluence 3.0.1 on a ms server 2003.

Pages which contain latex produce this error:

Unable to find DVI conversion log file

Many people mention permission issues. How can I solve them in ms server 2003? Thanks.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin probably can't find latex.exe, which must be installed manually.

Try:

- Installing MiKTeX
- Restarting Confluence

If this doesn't solve the issue, or if you have upgraded Confluence and need a plugin compatible with Confluence 4, then I would suggest the following: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.tensixtwo.conf.latexmath